# Sort a RecyclerView from a value that is generated in the Adapter and not an Object variable?

Tags: android, sorting, arraylist, android-recyclerview

Sorting an ArrayList from a value in the ArrayList is no problem, but I have an int that gets calculated directly in the Adapter and I prefer to keep it there, because it seems like a clean solution.

timeLeftinMinutes is the value I want to sort the RecyclerView for, but I don't know how to get it into the Activity (The exact calculation is not so important):

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    int dueHour = mTaskList.get(position).getDueHour();
    int dueMinute = mTaskList.get(position).getDueMinute();
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    int currentHour = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    int currentMinute = calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

    //correcting values to over 24 if necessary
    int mBedHourPlus24IfNecessary;
    if (mBedHour < mWakeUpHour || mBedHour == mWakeUpHour && mBedMinute < mWakeUpMinute) mBedHourPlus24IfNecessary = mBedHour + 24;
    else mBedHourPlus24IfNecessary = mBedHour;
    int mDueHourPlus24IfNecessary;
    if (dueHour < mWakeUpHour ) mDueHourPlus24IfNecessary = dueHour + 24;
    else mDueHourPlus24IfNecessary = dueHour;


    int timeLeftInMinutes;
    if (mDueHourPlus24IfNecessary > mBedHourPlus24IfNecessary || mDueHourPlus24IfNecessary == mBedHourPlus24IfNecessary && dueMinute > mBedMinute) {
        holder.mTimeLeft.setText(mContext.getResources().getString(R.string.while_sleeping));
        holder.mCardContainer.setCardBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(mContext, R.color.task_blue));
        timeLeftInMinutes = 999999999;
    } else {
        timeLeftInMinutes = (mDueHourPlus24IfNecessary * 60 + dueMinute) - (currentHour * 60 + currentMinute);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It is not a good idea to use `onBindViewHolder` because it is called only for the object that are going to appear on the screen and therefore you won't know the `timeLeftInMinutes` for all item.

A better solution would be to add, into your adapter, a method that would go through your array, computer the time for each item, save it into the item, notify the adapter that the list is ready

```
public void updateAndSort(List<MyObject> list) {
    //Go through all your item and computer their time left.
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        //Compute the value you need to compare for each item
        list.get(i).timeLeftInMinute = timeComputed...
    }

    //Then you order your list, for example ascendant
    Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<MyObject>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(MyObject o1, MyObject o2) {
            if (o1.timeLeftInMinute > o2.timeLeftInMinute) {
                return 1;
            } else {
                return -1;
            }
        }
    });

    //replace your mTaskList the sorted list to your adapter
    mTaskList = list;

    //notify the adapter to correctly display the times
    notifyDataSetChanged()

}
```

Comment: Thank you, that seems like a nice solution. Is that sorting method costly performance-wise? I think i should make 2 seperate methods, since i wanna update that time every minute, but only need sorting when i edit the list items.

And do you think it would be more efficient to - instead of sorting the whole list - just place every new or edited element to the right place? Or will there be no noticable difference? This sorting method seems much easier than checking where each new item belongs.

Comment: @FlorianWalther Or you can have the same method `update(List<MyObject> list, boolean shouldSort)` which will only run the sort if `shouldSort` is true. But don't complicate your life too much with complicated code, try and see if the performance are ok. You may also want to use a linkedlist to insure the list order.